# storing and displaying returned JSON object inside nodejs script

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

please see this code and help me guys, i want to display the json object values in some structured way, but when i test to get only the json structured form, i m not able to get the output. I want to  display values on webpage `localhost:3000/getscorelist` on webpage after my spawn child process ends, but i m getting the output on webpage as below.

*Issue*:
**Right now i m able to display the json object on the webpage, but i want to display the output in good form so that user can download it in either csv file or can view it.**

I m earlier able to get the csv file using the code below

```
 // var csv = output_array.toString();
 // res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=output.csv');
 // res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
// res.send(csv)
```

[image]

Also you can see there is space `""` in the red marked, which i think may create issue when i parse the json object as follows

[image]

My nodejs code from which i m executing `console.log(data.toString())`

```
app.post('/getscorelist', getscorelist);

var output_array = []

function getscorelist(req, res){

    csvData = req.files.csvfile.data.toString('utf8');
    csvData = csvData.split(/\r\n/)

    for (var i=1;i<csvData.length;i++){

        console.log(csvData[i])
        // Send request to python script
        var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
        var process = spawn('python', ["-u", "./test.py", csvData[i].trim()])

        process.stdout.on('data', function(data){

            output_array.push(data.toString().trim())

            console.log(data.toString())

            // If condition will run after all for loop element
            if(output_array.length == csvData.length){

                res.header("Content-Type",'application/json');
                var json = JSON.stringify(output_array, null, 2);
                res.send(json)

                // res.header("Content-Type",'application/json');
                // var myJSONString = JSON.stringify(output_array);
                // res.send(output_array)
                // const jsonString = JSON.stringify(output_array, 2);
                // res.send(jsonString)
                // received data in json object
                // var mystr = data;
                // res.send(jsonString)
                // var csv = output_array.toString();
                // res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=output.csv');
                // res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
                // console.log("Processing finished")
                // res.send(csv)
                // console.log(output_array.length)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Below is the console output of my code.

```
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\compodrank>node index.js
server running on port 3000
9015616
9015617
9015618
9015699
7843093
{"patentNumber": "US9015617", "title": "Display of supplementary information on a graphical user interface", "abstract": "Disclosed are method and apparatus for displaying supplementary information on a graphical user interface. A request for supplementary information is received. The supplementary information is retrieved and displayed in a reserved display field in a graphical user interface. The reserved display field may be configured by a user to adapt to specific applications, but remains stationary throughout the user session. The reserved display field does not obstruct any other display fields in the graphical user interface. A request for supplementary information may be generated by using a mouse to first position a cursor over an active display element. A request for supplementary information associated with the active display element may be generated by clicking the mouse, or by holding the cursor stationary for a time interval greater than a threshold dwell time.", "currentAssignee": "ATT Intellectual Property I LP", "inventor": "James Patrick Stapleton, James Anthony Gewecke, Justin Nicholas Marcucci, Lee Allan Culver, David Jason Krantz", "numberOfIndependentClaims": 3, "dependentPerIndependentClaims": 0.25, "lengthOfFirstClaim": "172", "numberOfReassignments": 0, "numberOfLitigations": "0", "sizeOfFamily": "6", "ageOfPatent": 12.9315, "legalStatus": "Active", "numberOfForwardCitations": 11, "numberOfBackwardCitations": 41, "numberOfClassifications": 21, "classifications": "[' G06F17/30386', ' G06F17/30884', ' G06F17/30017', ' G06F16/9562', ' G06F3/04847', ' G06F3/04842', ' G06F16/9577', ' G06F16/955', ' G06F40/106', ' G06F40/103', ' G06F17/211', ' G06F40/166', ' G06F16/40', 'G06F17/212', ' G06F40/00', ' G06F16/90', ' G06F16/20', ' G06F16/24', ' G06F16/00', ' G06F3/01', ' G06F3/00']", "industrialPotential": 1, "score": "38.2616"}

{"patentNumber": "US9015618", "title": "Methods and apparatus for processing application windows", "abstract": "An apparatus may include one or more memories and one or more processors. The one or more processors may be configured to execute instructions to facilitate providing a first window for display while hiding from display one or more additional windows. The instructions may facilitate receiving a switching input. The instructions may facilitate, in response to the switching input, providing a plurality of windows for display. The providing a plurality of windows may include changing a display view from the first window to the plurality of windows. The instructions may facilitate selecting one of the plurality of windows. The selecting one of the plurality of windows may include changing the display view from the plurality of windows to the selected one of the plurality of windows while hiding from display one or more other windows. Methods for displaying windows and machine-readable storage medium are also disclosed.", "currentAssignee": "Google LLC", "inventor": "Roma Rajni Shah, John Nicholas Jitkoff, Glen Murphy, Arnaud Claude Weber, Michael Feldstein, Alex Neely Ainslie", "numberOfIndependentClaims": 3, "dependentPerIndependentClaims": 0.2142, "lengthOfFirstClaim": "228", "numberOfReassignments": 1, "numberOfLitigations": "0", "sizeOfFamily": "10", "ageOfPatent": 9.9808, "legalStatus": "Active", "numberOfForwardCitations": 33, "numberOfBackwardCitations": 64, "numberOfClassifications": 15, "classifications": "[' G06F17/30905', ' H04M1/72445', ' G06F16/9577', ' H04M1/72403', ' H04M1/72561', ' G06F3/0481', ' G06F9/4443', ' G06F16/90', ' G06F16/00', ' G06F9/451', ' H04M1/00', ' G06F9/00', ' G06F9/06', ' G06F3/01', 'G06F3/00']", "industrialPotential": 1, "score": "46.274"}

{"patentNumber": "US7843093", "title": "Driving device", "abstract": "A stepping motor as a driving device has a stator with a plate part, and first and second outer magnetic pole parts axially extending from the plate part. A rotor formed by a rotary shaft and a core, each formed of a soft magnetic material, are disposed between the outer magnetic pole parts. The rotor has one axial end rotatably supported in the plate part. A magnet is rigidly fitted on an outer periphery of the rotor and magnetized such that different poles circumferentially alternate. A top plate is rigidly secured to the respective foremost ends of the pole parts and rotatably supports the other axial end of the rotor. The pole parts are engaged in a bobbin having a cover part covering the outer peripheral surface of the magnet. First and second coils are wound around the outer magnetic pole parts via the bobbin.", "currentAssignee": "Canon Inc", "inventor": "Masao Mizumaki", "numberOfIndependentClaims": 1, "dependentPerIndependentClaims": 0.5, "lengthOfFirstClaim": "373", "numberOfReassignments": 0, "numberOfLitigations": "0", "sizeOfFamily": "8", "ageOfPatent": 16.0136, "legalStatus": "Expired - Fee Related", "numberOfForwardCitations": 4, "numberOfBackwardCitations": 26, "numberOfClassifications": 5, "classifications": "[' H02K37/16', ' H02K37/10', ' H02K37/12', ' H02K37/14', 'H02K37/00']", "industrialPotential": 1, "score": "22.5619"}

{"patentNumber": "US9015616", "title": "Search initiation", "abstract": "A computer-implemented user input method includes sensing a user manipulation of a mobile device to present a keyboard, automatically presenting, in response to the sensed manipulation, a search entry area on a display of the user device, and activating the keyboard to provide input into the search entry area.", "currentAssignee": "Google LLC", "inventor": "Erick Tseng, Nickolas Jay Sears", "numberOfIndependentClaims": 4, "dependentPerIndependentClaims": 0.2666, "lengthOfFirstClaim": "177", "numberOfReassignments": 1, "numberOfLitigations": "0", "sizeOfFamily": "2", "ageOfPatent": 12.4904, "legalStatus": "Active", "numberOfForwardCitations": 92, "numberOfBackwardCitations": 33, "numberOfClassifications": 28, "classifications": "[' H04M1/72403', ' H04M1/72561', ' H04M1/72445', ' H04M1/0208', ' G06F1/1675', ' G06F9/4443', ' G06F1/1613', ' G06F3/0487', ' G06F3/0482', ' G06F1/1626', ' G06F1/1615', ' G06F1/1624', ' H04M1/0206', ' H04M1/0202', ' G06F3/0481', ' G06F1/1643', ' G06F1/1677', ' G06F1/1633', ' H04M1/0235', ' G06F3/0488', ' G06F1/1637', ' G06F9/451', ' G06F9/06', ' H04M1/00', ' G06F1/00', ' G06F9/00', ' G06F3/00', ' G06F3/01']", "industrialPotential": 1, "score": "57.0495"}

{"patentNumber": "US9015699", "title": "Methods and articles of manufacture for hosting a safety critical application on an uncontrolled data processing device", "abstract": "Methods and articles of manufacture for hosting a safety critical application on an uncontrolled data processing device are provided. Various combinations of installation, functional, host integrity, coexistence, interoperability, power management, and environment checks are performed at various times to determine if the safety critical application operates properly on the device. The operation of the SCA on the UDPD may be controlled accordingly.", "currentAssignee": "Abbott Diabetes Care Inc", "inventor": "Daniel M. Bernstein, Saeed Nekoomaram, Mark K. Sloan", "numberOfIndependentClaims": 1, "dependentPerIndependentClaims": 0.0263, "lengthOfFirstClaim": "159", "numberOfReassignments": 0, "numberOfLitigations": "0", "sizeOfFamily": "22", "ageOfPatent": 11.6109, "legalStatus": "Active", "numberOfForwardCitations": 59, "numberOfBackwardCitations": 100, "numberOfClassifications": 30, "classifications": "[' G06F2201/865', ' G06F11/3688', ' G06F19/3412', ' G06F11/3668', ' G06F11/3672', ' G06F11/0703', ' G06F11/0751', ' G06F11/3692', ' G06F2201/00', ' G06F11/0706', ' G06F11/0736', ' G06F11/0721', ' G06F1/3234', ' G06F9/5005', ' G06F11/004', ' G06F1/3203', ' G06F9/5011', ' G06F11/079', ' G06F1/3287', ' G16H40/00', ' G06F9/546', ' G16H40/40', ' G06F8/00', ' G06F8/60', ' G06F8/61', ' G06F1/26', ' G06F1/00', ' G06F9/06', ' G06F9/00', ' G06F9/46']", "industrialPotential": 1, "score": "51.4187"}

^C
C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\compodrank>

C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\compodrank>

C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\compodrank>
```

Comment: please help me guys

Comment: It's too much information here... Could you be more specific on where your problem is?

Comment: yes @MichaelRovinsky i m updating question

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky i have updated code

Comment: i want to display the extracted values which are inside the json object to display on the webpage and also on click to download in csv file

Comment: Try: const json = JSON.stringify(output_array, null, 2);

Comment: what about to get this json in csv file becoz ultimatly i need to save and display the resutl

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky i have udpated code

Comment: Hi are you there

Answer (score 0):

What kind of service are you designing?

- If you want to allow users to consumme json data, then just send them that and leave it to the client - ie the actual program consumming your data - do the right thing with it. If a user wants to look at nicely formatted json in their browser for instance, they can use a browser extension.
- On the other end, if your goal actually is to present users with a formatted view of your json data and allow for them to download a csv representation from a single endpoint, then you may want to return an htlm document instead.

Comment: Sounds good I think you got my view, yes this json data I want to show to end user. Please can you show me some code example that how I can extend this nodejs script to client side rendering becoz this nodejs works on server end only. Or I may be wrong. Please guide me

Comment: I m beginner in this nodejs and this is my first nodejs application which is working with scraper written in python. So any help from your side would always be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Earlier I worked with php, MySQL and html but that was easy. But I am finding difficulty in working with nodejs and json data dealing. Also becoz this json data I m getting from spawn process

Comment: r u there please see this question